# Why are my longs turning into ints?

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a JSP page, but I'm running into a null pointer at run time. In an attempt to isolate the problem, I hard-coded the expected variable response instead of using a getter (it was previously `action.getName(psi.getLong()) )`). Sure enough, I got an error when I tried to run the page with the raw long.

```
An error occurred at line: 70 in the jsp file: /auth/foo/viewBar.jsp
The literal 9000000000 of type int is out of range 

70:             <%long sarah = 9000000000; %>
71:             <td> <%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(""+action.getName(sarah)) %></td>
```

getName is defined elsewhere as follows

```
public String getName(long mid) throws DBException {
        try {
            return personnelDAO.getName(mid);
        } catch (fooException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception retrieving name";
        }
```

But judging by the above, I'd guess that the 9000000000 isn't even getting passed that far. Can .JSP not handle longs?

Furthermore, could this error have caused the nullpointer error I was experiencing at runtime, or is that a wholly separate error? (That's all the stacktrack says: `NullPointerException: null`)

Edit: D'oh. Using a factory, forgot to instantiate one of the DAOs I'm using. That'd be the cause of the NullPointer then. Case closed.

Comment: Try suffixing your long number with L like `long number = 900L;`

Comment: @Jigar - I already fixed it. It does, however, tell me that I am in need of caffeine or sleep; preferably the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

> 9000000000L.

You need to specify the type in this case.
Or use

> `new Long("9000000000")`

Comment: `new Long(9000000000)` won't work, as `9000000000` will still be interpreted as an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Change `long sarah = 9000000000;` to `long sarah = 9000000000L;`. Without the 'L' suffix, any integer literal is an `int` in Java.

Comment: @Stephen C: I guess you would agree if I changed that to "considers"?

Comment: Sort of.  The real issue is that the JLS says that an integer literal without a suffix is an `int` literal.  The compiler is just a piece of software that implements the JLS ... it doesn't have any "view" on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is going on here, you need to understand a bit about integer literals.

In Java there are two kinds of integer literals.

- A Long literal has a suffix 'L', and must fall in the range -2^63 to +2^63 - 1.  It has type `long`.
- An Int literal has no suffix, and must fall in the range -2^31 to +2^31 - 1.  It has type `int`.

An integer literal that falls outside of the prescribed range is a compilation error, no matter what the context.  Thus:

```
long sarah = 9000000000;
```

is a compilation error, despite the fact that that "number" is compatible with the type on the LHS.  Similarly:

```
Long fred = new Long(9000000000);
```

is a compilation error ... for the same reason.

The solution is to add an L suffix; e.g.

```
long sarah = 9000000000L;
Long fred = new Long(9000000000L);
```

---

(Actually, I told a small white lie in the above.  The JLS *actually* states that an Integer literal is unsigned, and that what looks like a "negative literal" is actually an expression using the Unary minus operator.  The legal integer literal values are therefore 0 to +2^31 - 1 (for int) and 0 to +2^63 - 1 (for long).  The literals 2^31 and 2^63 used to express Integer.MIN_VALUE and Long.MIN_VALUE are special cases ... they are *only* legal when preceded by Unary minus.)